# Does overflow hidden lead to faster rendering on scrollable regions

Tags: html, css, performance

If you have a div that you are using as a viewport into a much larger div (the view)

If you set the width and height of the view and it has `overflow: hidden` does it mean that the browser will not have to calculate the right most and bottom most position of all of the children elements in order to determine the maximum scroll region? And should we therefore get better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Overflow only clips things; this still requires the browser to actually render everything first. If you're looking to only selectively load elements based on scroll position, that's something to do with Javascript, and not HTML.

Comment: The point is that it should not have to go through all of the child regions in order to set the size of the scroll region.

Comment: @AranMulholland But that's not how DOM rendering works; and unless you have an excessive amount of content to load, it shouldn't even be a concern. Modern browsers are really, really good at rendering things quickly; they have to be. In this instance in particular it will still render everything because otherwise should the viewing area change for some reason, it can quickly and easily know what to display instead. And it can't even know what to display in the first place until after it renders everything.